# Route [x] not defined when using auth middleware

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I am making a website with laravel but i am getting an error while using middleware auth. it says Route[x] not defined.[image: error]

i am using laravel 5.8 please some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route you have written that has no named route so you need to specify name for that route like this

```
    Route::get('x', function() {
        //
    })->name('x')->middleware('auth');
```

for more information you can check here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes